# Algorithm to calculate a maximal string from a matrix.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, algorithms

I have stumbled upon an interesting question whilst working on my thesis.
You are given a matrix of pairwise distinct integers $A=(a_{i,j})$ with $1\leq i\leq k$ and $1\leq j \leq r$ and a tuple $(b_1, \dots, b_r)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^r b_i=k$.

You have to calculate the lexicographic maximal string $(a_{i_1, j_1}, a_{i_2, j_2}, \dots, a_{i_k, j_k})$ such that no $a_{i,j}$'s are from the same column and the number of $a_{i,j}$'s from row $l$ is exactly $b_l$ and $a_{i_1, j_1}<a_{i_2,j_2}<\dots < a_{i_k, j_k}$.

Are there any known, efficient, algorithms to do this?

An example would be:
$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 &3 \\ 
5&2&6
\end{pmatrix}$$
and $b=(2,1)$
The solution here would be $(3,4,5)$.

Comment: 1) You should give an example. 2) A certain similarity with questions on Young tableaux.

Comment: I added an example, could you maybe explain to which questions on Young tableaux it is similar?

Comment: If rows go from $1$ to $k$, $b$ indices should do the same?

Comment: This looks a bit like maximum weighted bipartite $b$-matching (which asks to find a set of coefficients from a matrix maximizing the total sum, with conditions imposed on rows and columns for the number of selected elements)

Answer (score 3):

**This can be solved in polynomial time.**

---

**Bipartite $b$-matching problem**

Lets recall the bipartite $b$-matching problem (formulated in terms of matrices):

Let $M\in\mathcal{M}_{k, r}$ be a boolean matrix. For each row $i$ and each column $j$, we have coefficients $b_{r_i}, b_{c_j}\in \mathbb{N}$ indicating the number of elements that should be selected in the corresponding row of column. We have $\sum_{i=1}^k b_{r_i} = \sum_{j=1}^r b_{c_j}$. The bipartite $b$-matching problem asks if it is possible to find a set of True elements satisfying the requirements on every row and column.

---

**The algorithm**

Let's turn back to the problem.

We sort the values in the matrix by decreasing order and number these from $v_1$ to $v_{kr}.

We first want to see if it is possible to find a string beginning by $a_r$ (that's the best we can hope)

We set $b_{r_i} = b_i$ for all $i$ and $b_{c_j} = 1$ for all column. We set to true $a_1$ to $a_{r-1}$ and we $a_r$ as selected (this is not an inconvenience to force it to be selected, we can reduce to the classical $b$-matching problem by decreasing the $b$ values by $1$ on its row and its column). If we can find a $b$-matching for this problem, this is all good, this means that we can choose as a string $a_ra_{r-1}...a_1$.

If not, we set to true $a_r$ and force $a_{r+1}$ to be selected. We keep going like this until we find a satisfiable $b$-matcing problem (this will happen at some point.

Once we find a value for the first character of the string, we delete the corresponding column (or just decrease the corresponding $b$-values by one), and we repeat the same thing from the start to find the second character, and so one.

Clearly, this will require a polynomial number of steps, and the $b$-matching problem is solvable in polynomial time.

---

**How to solve the bipartite $b$-matching problem**

They are a lot of specialized algorithms that were developed for $b$-matching. For bipartite $b$-matching, you can also formulate it as a linear program (thanks to total unimodularity).

In your case, because you have only $1$-values for the columns, you have an efficient reduction for standard bipartite matching, for which it is easier to find implementations: just duplicate each row $i$ $b_{r_i}$ times.